# How do you get IBM MobileFirst Platform ChallengeHandler to handle very large responses correctly?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

When working with a large-sized data response from an HTTP Adapter, the size of the response appears to cause our challenge handler to fire a `handleChallenge()` method.

My question is, why would the size of the response cause the mobilefirst security challenge handler to fire, when the session is still valid?

More Details:
Our application uses an ISAM security appliance with Header based authentication. When an HTTP adapter call we make comes back with a content-length greater than 20,377, the adapter call triggers the `handleChallenge()` method of our challenge handler. When inspecting the response, we have seen that the responseJSON is actually populated with our required data, so really the `handleChallenge` should never have fired.

When we ping the adapter directly through the browser with the same parameters, it works fine. We've been able to isolate that this problem is occurring in the worklight.js / mobilefirst realm.

Does anyone have any idea if, or why, the Challenge Handler in worklight.js would not function as expected with a very large response size?

Comment: normally handleChallenge() should not fire unless isCustomResponse() has first been called, and it returns true. Does your isCustomResponse() method fire? If it does, I would double-check your logic in isCustomResponse(), the example code in tutorials is not very robust, conceivably your large response has data that gives a false positive.

Comment: Is your isCustomResponse triggered?

Comment: @cdizzle please respond.

Comment: We ended up ( sort of ) diagnosing it. At a certain payload size, the "/*secure {" fell off the response ( of which we're still not certain why. Our loginChallengeHandler function was based off of some example we found in some IBM documentation, and would improperly mark the response as a login form if the /*secure wasn't present. Once we tightened up the challenge handler, it worked.

Comment: @Cdizzle Can you write the above comment as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that it should. There is no reason for it not to.
If you have not been able to resolve this otherwise, my suggestion is to open an IBM PMR (support ticket) to have the development team investigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up ( sort of ) diagnosing it. At a certain payload size, the "/*secure {" fell off the response ( of which we're still not certain why. Our loginChallengeHandler function was based off of some example we found in some IBM documentation, and would improperly mark the response as a login form if the /*secure wasn't present. Once we tightened up the challenge handler, it worked.